# Eloquent Subquery using models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to turn this raw sql to eloquent

```
SELECT x.* from 
(SELECT * from clients where office_id IN(74,129,19)) AS x 
where 
x.firstname like '%parker%' or 
x.lastname like '%parker%'
```

My model is `Client`

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out the answer using the

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

```
$office_ids = [74,129,19];
Client::with('office')->whereIn('office_id',$office_ids)->where(function(Builder $dbQuery){

....

})
```